# リキッドレイアウト × 幅の異なる画像 × 横並び の場合の高さの調整方法

Tags: html, css

リキッドレイアウトでHTMLを組んだ際に、画像サイズも自動的に縮小されて欲しいと思い、widthにパーセンテージを指定しました。
幅の異なる画像を隙間なく並べた場合に、縮尺の関係から縦幅がずれてしまい見栄えがよくありません。
この現象を解消したいのですが良い方法はありますでしょうか。
全体的にリキッドレイアウトにしたいので、heightに具体的なサイズを指定することはできません。
以下が当該箇所のHTMLです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="95%" bgcolor="#FFF" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td>
<!-- wrapper : start -->
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="max-width:700px; margin:auto;" class="email-container">
<tr>
    <td>

        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td width="49%" style="vertical-align:top; font-size:0; line-height:0;">
                    <img  width="100%"  src="img/left.jpg" style="display: block;" alt="LEFT">
                </td>
                <td width="51%" style="vertical-align:top; font-size:0; line-height:0;">
                    <img  width="100%" src="img/right.jpg" style="display: block;" alt="RIGHT">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </td>
</tr>    
</table>
<!-- wrapper : end -->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下、一例です。

```css
body,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.liquid {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.liquid li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.liquid li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: initial;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
ul.liquid li {
  position: relative;
}
ul.liquid li >* {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="liquid">
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/187/191" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/187/191)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/191/117" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/191/117)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/182/123" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/182/123)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/199/187" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/199/187)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/109/119" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/109/119)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/196/173" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/196/173)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/193/154" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/193/154)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/130/163" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/130/163)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/136/128" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/136/128)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/176/118" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/176/118)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/125/138" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/125/138)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/197/146" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/197/146)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/136/149" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/136/149)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/108/178" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/108/178)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/179/157" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/179/157)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/131/186" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/131/186)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/120/135" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/120/135)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/146/164" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/146/164)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/131/156" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/131/156)"></a> </li>
  <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/181/170" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/181/170)"></a> </li>
</ul>
```

単位`vw`は[Android4.3以下で動作しないので](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)、サポートしたい場合は`px`などの固定値をjavascriptで動的に書き換える、などの対応が必要です。

> 参考:

- [CSSでblock要素を上下左右中央寄せにする、イマドキの方法。 | バシャログ。 | 横浜でWeb制作を行うシーブレインスタッフによる技術情報ブログ](http://bashalog.c-brains.jp/14/08/06-100100.php)
- [html - Scale image to fit a bounding box - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994493/scale-image-to-fit-a-bounding-box)